# is it possible to get a link to a microsoft teams chat with someone given his email?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to know if there is a way to get a link for a chat with a user whom i have the email address in order to redirect him from my application to microsoft teams site (or the application) via a "contact option".

Comment: If you are trying to fetch the chat of a specific user you can try following [Get Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)Graph API.

Comment: i don't want to fetch the whole chat, i want to fetch the link to that chat with the user so i can redirect anyone from my app to teams app or website

Comment: I'm not getting you what do you mean by link to that chat with the user, is it link to user specific chat in 1:1 scope?  You can fetch the [chatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) for a specific user through Graph API